# Why is HAProxy sending a 301 (Moved Permanently) to redirect my traffic to my backend?

Tags: redirect

My HAProxy box is sending a 301 and redirecting my http traffic directly to the configured backend. I do not have it configured to do so. Here is the config. Any ideas on what could possibly be wrong?
Thanks
Greg
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local2
    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param   2048

# turn on stats unix socket
stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    retries                 3
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    maxconn                 3000

frontend input_8081
    bind 192.168.119.111:8081
    default_backend out_8081

frontend input_8082
    bind 192.168.119.111:8082 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/proxy_server.pem
    default_backend out_8082

backend out_8081
    server ad-video 192.168.115.1:8081


backend out_8082
    server ad-video 192.168.115.1:8082
```

Answer (score 1):

Greg,

Your server must be generating the 301.
Sharing the logs generated by HAProxy may confirm this.

Baptiste

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the server I am trying to proxy requires a full URL from the proxy to it's index.html page or it returns a 301 error (Moved Permanently).
Thanks to everyone for giving this a look.

Greg